# Display records from SQLite into ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

Although this question has been asked many times on here, I just can't find the proper answer to fit my code. I realize it may be something small, but I just can't seem to find the problem.

This is my RunDatabase Class.

```
     // Getting All Contacts
public List<RecordLists> getAllContacts() {
    List<RecordLists> contactList = new ArrayList<RecordLists>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RecordLists contact = new RecordLists();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setUserName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setPassword(cursor.getString(4));

            String name = cursor.getString(1) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(2) + "\n" + cursor.getString(3) + "\n" + cursor.getString(4);
            AllRecords.ArrayofName.add(name);
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Now I am calling this in another activity which is AllRecords.java and the code is:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        try {
            RunDatabase db = new RunDatabase(this);

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all Records..");


            List<RecordLists> contacts = db.getAllContacts();   
            ArrayAdapter<RecordLists> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RecordLists>(this, R.layout.records, contacts);
            for (RecordLists cn : contacts) 
            {   
            final String log = "Id: "+cn.getId()+ " ,UserName " + cn.getUserName() + " ,FirstName: " + cn.getFirstName() + " ,LastName: " + cn.getLastName() + " ,Password " + cn.getPassword();
                // Writing Contacts to log      
            Log.d("Name: ", log);

                    RecordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);
                    RecordList.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
                    RecordList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: If tou are using cursor then use cursor adapter instead of array adapter to populate list view

Comment: Whats your problem and where you stuck? Have you tried anything? What you get output?

Comment: @Siva but it's throwing errors ...

Comment: @Sripathi I have debugged it and run it it's not throwing any exception or error but not showing any records either ...

Comment: What errors post logcat

Comment: Try to use custom adapter. Please check with these links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517031/display-records-from-sqlite-into-listview
http://theopentutorials.com/tag/android-custom-arrayadapter-example/
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: @Siva I have uploaded the logcat but I can't see anything special .

Comment: You have used the arrayadapter and it will allow you to use a textview as the layout for the listview row. Custom adapter is the better choice for you.

Comment: I can't see any logcat in the question and on how to implement the cursor adapter I gave example in my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor adapter is the best option to populate the list view and data returned is from database.. Below is the sample code for cursor adapter change as per your requirement.

```
public class adapter extends CursorAdapter{

        public adapter (Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //here write code for populating list view

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflate=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v=inflate.inflate( R.layout.records, parent,false);
            bindView(v, context, cursor);
            return v;
        }


    }
```

Now call the adapter by creating object wherever required.